# How do i print smaller value?

Tags: python

I am very new to python, I write below few lines of code but not able to print smallest number from the input.

```
largest = 0
smallest = 0

while True:
    num = raw_input("Enter a number:")
    if num == "done" : break
    try:
        num = int(num)
    except:
        print "invalid"
        continue
    if num is smallest:
          smallest = num
    if num > largest:
          largest = num

print "Minimum", smallest, "Maximum", largest
```

below is my output, it does print correct largest value (whatever i input) but smallest is always zero.

```
Enter a number:34
Enter a number:12000
Enter a number:dds
invalid
Enter a number:done
Minimum 0 Maximum 12000=====> see minimum is "0" should be 34?
```

Answer (score 2):

That's the expected behaviour. In fact, your second statement reads:

```
smallest = 0
```

`0` is less than `34`, so `smallest` won't be updated.

A possible solution is initializing `smallest` and `largest` from the first element read:

```
largest = None
smallest = None

while True:
    num = raw_input("Enter a number:")
    if num == "done" : break
    try:
        num = int(num)
    except:
        print "invalid"
        continue

    if smallest is None: # or largest is None, it's the same
        smallest = num
        largest = num

    if num < smallest:
          smallest = num
    if num > largest:
          largest = num

print "Minimum", smallest, "Maximum", largest
```

Besides, you have what appears to be a typo or a misconception about the operator `is`. This:

```
if num is smallest:
    smallest = num
```

Should be:

```
if num < smallest:
    smallest = num
```